# How can I print out a single stylesheet or javascript link?

Tags: php, themes, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I know I can use `enqueue_script` and `enqueue_style` to register scripts and stylesheets, however I'm trying to print out just the link to the adminbar css:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-bar-css' \
href='http://mysite.com/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.css?ver=20111209' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

I could just include that text on my page but I was hoping for something like

```
wp_print_script('admin-bar-css')
```

Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to print a single style:

```
wp_print_styles('admin-bar');
```

to print a single script:

```
wp_print_scripts('admin-bar');
```

note that the handle must be registered first using wp_register_style() or wp_register_script().

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style

Comment: thx. i also found this helpful: `wp_print_scripts('jquery');`

Comment: i think you have a typo in your print script syntax

Comment: you mean, wp_print_styles doesn't also print scripts? copy, paste FAIL.  fixed.  thanks.